# SQL read csv formatting in tables

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, import, format

The data I have is formatted in this way:

```
Apfeltasche;E1412,E1442,E410,E500,E920,E471,E330 \
Apfeltüte;E300,E501\
Balsamico Dressing;E224,E150d,E262,E500,E415\
Barbecue Sauce;E415,E1404\
Big Mac;E471,E472e,E300,E481,E202,E263,E331,E330,E415,E322, E160a,E160c\
Butter;NULL\
Cheeseburger;E471,E472e,E330,E481,E300,E331,E202,E263,E322,E160a,E160c\
```

The first column is the name of a product and the codes on the right are additives (e-num). I have one table for products that combines the name with an auto-increment id. And I have a table that stores the connection between the product-id and the e-num.

So there are two problems: First I need to load the product-names into the product table to get a valid id for the product. Then I have to combine the ID with the e-nums. But the e-nums are seperated with commas which would have to be a seperate row each time in the table connecting id and e-num. So I would kind of have to do two splits.

Iam really not finding any way to do that. And unfortunatly Iam not allowed to change the csv data to fit my model better. How would you do that ? Thanks guys :)

Comment: You could write a script for this in for example PHP, you cannot use the simple import machanisms. ALternatively, you load this using the simple import mechanisms into a temporary table and then write queries to do the splitting of strings and creation of the data into the real tables

Comment: a pure sql solution is to load the csv in a temporary table and then process it, with a trigger. A split function for the e-nuber can be find here on site